# How to default to "Append New Result" in Workbench/J?

Tags: sql-workbench-j

Each time I open a new tab in Workbench/J the default setting is to not append new results in the results bar. I earned my stripes in Microsoft SQL Server so I'm used to this being default behavior and consistently forget to enable it each time I open a new tab - which becomes painful when I am running long queries.

Anyway to make this the DEFAULT behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[As documented in the manual](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/options.html#options-append-results-default):

Tools -> Options -> Data display -> Append results:

[image: options]